# custom shape for markers using angular google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am trying to use the angular google maps(http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) directive in my application, so converting my code to work with that directive and stuck up in that process to apply custom shape to the markers.

Anybody who is familiar with angular google maps can help me to resolve this issue, please check the below mentioned code written in plain google maps library and let me know how to make this code working with the angular google maps directive.

```js
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latLng,
  map: map,
  icon: {
    url: 'path/to/icon',
    origin:new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor:new google.maps.Point(3,4)
  },
  shape: {
    coords:[0, 6, 7, 0, 16, 0, 23, 6, 12, 12],
    type:"poly"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I found the solution here, we need to set that as an attribute to OPTIONS object as mentioned below:

```
                markers.push({
                    latitude: site.latitude,
                    longitude: site.longitude,
                    id: 1,
                    icon: {
                        url: 'path/to/icon',
                        origin: origin,
                        anchor: anchor
                    },
                    options: {
                        shape: {
                            coords: phaseMarker.coords,
                            type: "poly"
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**Note:** I tried this even before posting this question, but that didn't worked well due to duplicate ID attribute for markers, so make sure we have unique ID for each marker if we have a set of markers in  our map.